# How to help condor find the file it should execute in a job?

Tags: condor

I am trying to run a job, but condor can't seem to find my file.

I've made sure that:

1. the file is there by doing an ls and cat on its absolute path
2. run it from a condor interactive session
3. give it the right permissions so that it runs it.

I've done that but I get this error:

```
(automl-meta-learning) miranda9~/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/experiments/meta_learning $ cat condor_job_log_69.out 
000 (069.000.000) 10/21 11:06:06 Job submitted from host: <130.126.112.32:9618?addrs=130.126.112.32-9618+[--1]-9618&noUDP&sock=3715279_f2e6_4>
...
001 (069.000.000) 10/21 11:06:07 Job executing on host: <172.22.224.111:9618?addrs=172.22.224.111-9618+[--1]-9618&noUDP&sock=807_1d04_3>
...
007 (069.000.000) 10/21 11:06:07 Shadow exception!
        Error from slot1_3@vision-01.cs.illinois.edu: Failed to execute '/home/miranda9/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/experiments/meta_learning/meta_learning_experiments_submission.py': (errno=2: 'No such file or directory')
        0  -  Run Bytes Sent By Job
        0  -  Run Bytes Received By Job
...
012 (069.000.000) 10/21 11:06:07 Job was held.
        Error from slot1_3@vision-01.cs.illinois.edu: Failed to execute '/home/miranda9/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/experiments/meta_learning/meta_learning_experiments_submission.py': (errno=2: 'No such file or directory')
        Code 6 Subcode 2
...
(automl)
```

but the file is clearly there:

```
(automl-meta-learning) miranda9~/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/experiments/meta_learning $ ls -lah /home/miranda9/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/experiments/meta_learning/meta_learning_experiments_submission.py
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 miranda9 miranda9 22K Oct 20 14:54 /home/miranda9/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/experiments/meta_learning/meta_learning_experiments_submission.py
```

I don't understand why condor can't find it. Any ideas? I'm not the sys admin so I don't even know how to start debugging this.

btw my submission script:

```
####################
#
# Experiments script
# Simple HTCondor submit description file
#
# reference: https://gitlab.engr.illinois.edu/Vision/vision-gpu-servers/-/wikis/HTCondor-user-guide#submit-jobs
#
# chmod a+x test_condor.py
# chmod a+x experiments_meta_model_optimization.py
# chmod a+x meta_learning_experiments_submission.py
# chmod a+x download_miniImagenet.py
#
# condor_submit -i
# condor_submit job.sub
#
####################

# Executable   = meta_learning_experiments_submission.py
# Executable = automl-proj/experiments/meta_learning/meta_learning_experiments_submission.py
# Executable = ~/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/experiments/meta_learning/meta_learning_experiments_submission.py
Executable = /home/miranda9/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/experiments/meta_learning/meta_learning_experiments_submission.py

## Output Files
Log          = condor_job.$(CLUSTER).log.out
Output       = condor_job.$(CLUSTER).stdout.out
Error        = condor_job.$(CLUSTER).err.out

# Use this to make sure 1 gpu is available. The key words are case insensitive.
REquest_gpus = 1
# requirements = ((CUDADeviceName = "Tesla K40m")) && (TARGET.Arch == "X86_64") && (TARGET.OpSys == "LINUX") && (TARGET.Disk >= RequestDisk) && (TARGET.Memory >= RequestMemory) && (TARGET.Cpus >= RequestCpus) && (TARGET.gpus >= Requestgpus) && ((TARGET.FileSystemDomain == MY.FileSystemDomain) || (TARGET.HasFileTransfer))
# requirements = (CUDADeviceName == "Tesla K40m")
# requirements = (CUDADeviceName == "Quadro RTX 6000")
requirements = (CUDADeviceName != "Tesla K40m")

# Note: to use multiple CPUs instead of the default (one CPU), use request_cpus as well
Request_cpus = 8

# E-mail option
Notify_user = me@gmail.com
Notification = always

Environment = MY_CONDOR_JOB_ID= $(CLUSTER)

# "Queue" means add the setup until this line to the queue (needs to be at the end of script).
Queue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your executable is a python script.  Linux will report "no such file or directory" when the script itself exists, but the interpreter listed on the "#!" doesn't exist on the system.  Could this be what is happening here?  What is the first line of this script look like?

Comment: yes that was the issue I used to have arguments to some other HPC manager at the top with the wrong file to python. Now I have this and it works: `#!/home/miranda9/.conda/bin/python3.7`

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that at the top of my python submission script I had arguments for other clusters not related to condor so the wrong path to the python executable was there. I fixed it by removing that and adding this line to my python submission script:

```
#!/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning/bin/python
```

in fact to find the python path for your current env do:

```
which python
```